# How to disable authorization pop up on Android?

Tags: android, adb

In my device, whenever I connect it to a system, a pop up message asking for authorization comes up. Only after I authorize, I'm able to use adb. I'm building my own system, and display is not coming up properly, so to debug I need to use adb, but as adb is unauthorized I'm unable to use it. As display is not working, I do not see the popup message. Is there any way by which I can disable this authorization pop up? I got to know of some disable-verity option, but couldn't find it in adb 1.0.32.
Any idea on this?

Comment: why won't you just populate `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys` with your key? alternatively you could disable `adb` authentication with `ro.adb.secure=0`

Comment: @AlexP. The build prop tweak `ro.adb.secure=0` didn't work for me. Could you elaborate this. Im using old adb version that doesn't support this authorization mode, and I don't want to update adb . Instead I want to disable such authorization from device end.

Answer (score 3):

**adb disable-verity** is available as of this version:

```
$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
Revision 09a0d98bebce-android
```

---

To update adb on Linux you could

**1. Download *android-sdk_[latest-version]-linux.tgz* from here:**

https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

**2. Extract the file:**

`$ tar -zxvf android-sdk_[latest-version]-linux.tgz`

**3. Download platform-tools packages:**

`$ sudo android-sdk-linux/tools/android update sdk -t platform-tools --no-ui`

**4. Set downloaded adb version as default:**

`$ sudo mv android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb`

---

Now you are able to execute `$ adb disable-verity`

Comment: Only problem: You need the device to be authorized to run `disable-verity`. He cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 versions of ADB.EXE purporting to be 1.0.32.

Version of size & date below has support for command;

`adb.exe    1 011 200   2015-03-24 17:15    -a--`

`adb <enter>` gives (among other reponses);

adb disable-verity           - disable dm-verity checking on USERDEBUG builds