# How to trust adb through SSH in Android

Tags: android, bash, ssh, adb

I have a rooted pixel 3 device with magisk installed connected to a mac. I want to work on the device through the mac while connected remotely. Sometimes, I need to restart the android device - when I do, it sometimes stops trusting the mac computer it's connected to.

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895208/how-to-disable-authorization-pop-up-on-android) [about](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/165909/get-adb-to-trust-all-computers) disabling `dm-verity` to always trust the computer, but I'd like to avoid these kinds of solutions - they're insecure, complicated, and risk compromising the device.

Instead, I debugged the android device - I saw that whenever I give trust to the mac it's connected to, two files are generated:

```
/data/misc/adb/adb_keys
/data/misc/adb/adb_temp_keys.xml
```

Both of which contain the public adb key of the mac device, which can be found in

```
~/.android/adbkey.pub
```

What I tried to do is connect to the android via [SSH](http://www.galexander.org/software/simplesshd/), and when I lose trust I can push the files from the mac to the android by using [scp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy_protocol):

```
scp -P2222 ~/.android/adbkey.pub user@ip:/sdcard/test
ssh ...
su # using magisk
cp /sdcard/test/adbkey.pub /data/misc/adb/adb_keys
cp /data/misc/adb/adb_keys /data/misc/adb/adb_keys.xml # with some format changes
reboot
```

I hoped that would get the android device to trust the mac device, but when I run `adb-devices`, it's still unauthorized.

I've tried restarting `adbd` on android as well, hoping it would relook the files to authorize the mac, but that didn't work either.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or how can this be achieved?

Comment: Which Android OS is running on the Pixel phone? When overwriting files in `/data/misc/adb/` I would make sure to correct permissions, file owner and file group.

Comment: @Robert Hi, thank you. The Android device is running version10, I'm flexible with this though - I wouldn't mind flushing an Android 11 Image if that would help. Also, yeah - I see the file is pushed there with the same permissions

Comment: Permissions may be the same but I doubt that the new file will get also `system:shell` for user:group as I can see it on my device for those files.

Comment: @Robert Do you think that's whats stopping me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I authorized the phone on the mac with persistence ticked, copied the files in /data/misc/adb to a tmp folder, and then when it goes unauthorized I can reconnect via SSH and copy the files back, then restart the adb server on the PC (adb kill-server, adb start-server).